# Problemas al utilizar UpdateDoc en Firebase / React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

al utilizar el UpdateDoc en mi código para actualizar una colección en el Firebase, este no hace el cambio. Ya he cambiado las reglas del Firestore, borrar la coleccion y volverla a crear y sigue persistiendo. adjunto código. según estuve investigando, me decian que eran las reglas del Firestore, pero ya permití la escritura y la lectura de la data. Quedo pendiente de cualquier comentario. Estoy haciendo un chat y cuando hago un search buscando un usuario, y clickeo su nombre, esta supuesto a actualizarme los datos en la colección "userChats".

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import {
  collection,
  query,
  where,
  getDocs,
  setDoc,
  doc,
  updateDoc,
  serverTimestamp,
  getDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./firebase.js";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
const Search = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [err, setErr] = useState(false);

  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "users"),
      where("displayName", "==", username)
    );

    try {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        setUser(doc.data());
      });
    } catch (err) {
      setErr(true);
    }
  };

  const handleKey = (e) => {
    e.code === "Enter" && handleSearch();
  };

  const handleSelect = async () => {
    //check whether the group(chats in firestore) exists, if not create
    const combinedId =
      currentUser.uid > user.uid
        ? currentUser.uid + user.uid
        : user.uid + currentUser.uid;
    try {
      const res = await getDoc(doc(db, "chats", combinedId));

      if (!res.exists()) {
        //create a chat in chats collection
        await setDoc(doc(db, "chats", combinedId), { messages: [] });

        //create user chats
        await updateDoc(doc(db, "userChats", currentUser.uid), {
          [combinedId + ".userInfo"]: {
            uid: user.uid,
            displayName: user.displayName,
      
          },
          [combinedId + ".date"]: serverTimestamp(),
        
        });
        console.log(user.displayName);
        await updateDoc(doc(db, "userChats", user.uid), {
          [combinedId + ".userInfo"]: {
            uid: currentUser.uid,
            displayName: currentUser.displayName,
          },
          [combinedId + ".date"]: serverTimestamp(),
        });
       
      }
    } catch (err) {}

    setUser(null);
    setUsername("")
  };
  return (
    <div className="search">
      <div className="searchForm">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Find a user"
          onKeyDown={handleKey}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          value={username}
        />
      </div>
      {err && <span>User not found!</span>}
      {user && (
        <div className="userChat" onClick={handleSelect}>
          <img src={user.photoURL} alt="" />
          <div className="userChatInfo">
            <span>{user.displayName}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

adjunto reglas del Firestore, evidencia y estructura de muestra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read,write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Adjunto también la muestra de la estructura del userChats.

```
 userChats Collection:
  Document 1 (currentUser.uid):
    - Chat1 (ID): 
      - userInfo:
        - uid: (ID of the other user)
        - displayName: (Name of the other user)
      - date: (Date of the last message)
    - Chat2 (ID):
      - userInfo:
        - uid: (ID of the other user)
        - displayName: (Name of the other user)
      - date: (Date of the last message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Listo, el problema estaba en que en el componente registro, el "usersChat" tenia una s en el medio, y en el componente Search se llamaba "userchat."

Comment: Aquí una pregunta se cierra cuando no cumple con los criterios para estar en [es.so]. Lo que deberías hacer es [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta (aunque de hecho tu pregunta probablemente termine cerrada porque tu problema se debió a un error tipográfico). Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.